# Java WebRTC video streaming

Tags: java, video-streaming, webrtc

I want to get some advice. I have to implement java server which will stream video from user to other clients. On client side will be using WebRTC. Can you give me some ideas how to implement this? Thank you)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a media server that has WebRTC capabilities to do that. Don't try to write one on your own.

Here are a few open source alternatives: [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/), [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/), [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/)

If you plan on using an open source one, then I suggest you also understand the realities of these options - some got acquired, which changed a bit how they operate and how solid a solution they may be for you: https://bloggeek.me/twilio-acquires-kurento/

Answer (score 0):

Janus video room demo is doing that. Although Janus is not written in Java, and I would say it is less than rock solid, it works quite well for this purpose.

We could not make Kurento working (last year). It seemed having odd requirements of a specific Linux distribution and version, and even once it was working fine, it just stopped working for no reason a month after.

Kurento *does* offer a lot more than Janus, OTOH you don't need those features. Using simple WebRTC and Janus makes this use case possible.

There is no need to write any Java server. Clients can send the video stream right from a HTML5 webpage, and viewers can view it right in HTML5. Janus examples show the actual code.